# Conditional compilation error/warning when using razor syntax in javascript (cc_on does not exist in this context)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, conditional-comments

I am using Razor syntax in an ASP.NET MVC3 View inside a JavaScript code  but I get a "conditional compilation is off" warning. I searched for it and found out that using  `/*@cc_on @*/` before the code turns it on. But I get an error "The name 'cc_on' does not exist in the current context". Any ideas? Where exactly am I supposed to give `/*@cc_on @*/` ?

**Sample Code:**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     @*
          - some multi-line comment stuff here
          - apparently the at signs cause syntax errors --argh!
     *@ 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show the code that emits the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just guess... Try the following:

```
/*@("@cc_on @")*/
```

or

```
@("/*@cc_on @*/")
```

whatever you prefer

I hope it's correct Razor syntax. An idea is to render this value as a string as `@` is used by razor (in your case compiler thinks that you want to output `@cc_on` variable which isn't declared)